# How to set right navigation bar button title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

How do I programatically set my right navigation bar button's title. I've tried

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Test"];
```

and have also tried creating an outlet for the button and then trying to assign it a value.

```
self.rightBarButton.titleLabel.text = @"Test";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:target action:action];
```

Answer (score 7):

For **Swift** use this,

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("methodName"))
```

Set Color of Title using this,

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this, it works:

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"New Title";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple option for Swift 3:

```
let rightButton = self.editButtonItem
rightButton.title = "My Button"
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for swift 3:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Test"
```

But the button has to be of custom type, otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For Single Navigation Button

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(yourFunctionWithObjcKeyword))
```

For Multiple Navigation Buttons

```
let add = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(yourFunctionWithObjcKeyword))

let edit = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit, target: self, action: #selector(yourFunctionWithObjcKeyword))

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [add, edit]
```

> Note: you must embed your controller inside UINavigationController to make above code work. In case of UITableViewController and UICollectionViewController, this code doesn't work.